# Change multiplie values in a table with a single update query

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

Lets say students can be in queue for multiple different courses. Each courses have its own queue with students.

The table got following: **StudentID**(int), **CourseID**(int), **Accepted**(bool) and **QueueIndex**(int). Every `studentID` got different `QueueIndex`'s for each `courseID`.

How do I update every `QueueIndex` for all queues once a student is e.g. removed where he belonged?

E.g. the student A got `QueueIndex` 5 in Course A and `QueueIndex` 3 in Course B. I want every other student above that `QueueIndex` and `CourseID` get a decreased --value, so the next student in Course A who had `QueueIndex` 6 will have `QueueIndex` 5 instead etc.

```
UPDATE [Register] 
SET QueueIndex = QueueIndex -1
WHERE QueueIndex > 0
AND (decrease QueueIndex for every CourseID where that specific StudentID left the queue);
```

Is this possible with a single query?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one student will be in there multiple times if they are in multiple courses? If they left one course then...

```
UPDATE table SET queue = queue - 1 WHERE queue > queuenumber /*the student that was removed queue number*/ AND course = courseid /*the course id of the course that the student was removed from */
```

I'm on my phone so sorry if there are typos. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to update the queueindex at all?

```
SELECT StudentID, CourseID, 
    (SELECT Count(StudentID) FROM Register R 
    WHERE R.CourseID = Register.CourseID AND 
    R.QueueIndex <= Register.QueueIndex) AS QueueNr
FROM Register
```

This would give you the queueindex in order no matter who was removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use trigger to do the update when a DELETE statement is fired. Below code may help you:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Delete_Update_Register ON dbo.Register
    FOR DELETE
AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  Register
        SET     QueueIndex = QueueIndex - 1
        WHERE   QueueIndex > 0
                AND QueueIndex > ( SELECT   QueueIndex
                                   FROM     deleted
                                 )
    END
```

This trigger will update all the QueueIndex only for QueueIndex greater than the deleted QueueIndex.
Otherwise, if you want to update all QueueIndex just comment out the AND condition from WHERE Clause.